# Send and XML base64 with curl

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl

I'm trying to send an xml file to consume a service and I get the following error

{
"statusCode": 400,
"errorMessage": "Error al decodificar documento.",
"errorReason": "Estructura del documento inválida. Ha ocurrido un error al convertir documento de base64 a string."
}

English

{
"statusCode": 400,
"errorMessage": "Error decoding document.",
"errorReason": "Invalid document structure. An error occurred while converting document from base64 to string."
}

```
    $xmlstr = '<Invoice>
   <cbc:ID>123</cbc:ID>
   <cbc:IssueDate>2011-09-22</cbc:IssueDate>
   <cac:InvoicePeriod>
      <cbc:StartDate>2011-08-01</cbc:StartDate>
      <cbc:EndDate>2011-08-31</cbc:EndDate>
   </cac:InvoicePeriod>
   <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
      <cac:Party>
         <cac:PartyName>
            <cbc:Name>Custom Cotter Pins</cbc:Name>
         </cac:PartyName>
      </cac:Party>
   </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
   <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
      <cac:Party>
         <cac:PartyName>
            <cbc:Name>North American Veeblefetzer</cbc:Name>
         </cac:PartyName>
      </cac:Party>
   </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
   <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
      <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="CAD">100.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
   </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
   <cac:InvoiceLine>
      <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="CAD">100.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
      <cac:Item>
         <cbc:Description>Cotter pin, MIL-SPEC</cbc:Description>
      </cac:Item>
   </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>';
    $encoded = base64_encode($xmlstr);
    $url = 'https://myUrl';
    $token = 'myToken';

    $params = array(
        'documento' => $encoded
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Content-type: text/plain',
        'token: '.$token
     );


    $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($params));
        

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        if(!$response) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return $response;
        }
```

My xml file was tested in postman and an expected error response was received. In this case, it is as if I sent it incorrectly and it was not identified by the service

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How could we possibly know what is wrong, you have not given us _any_ specification or documentation, on how exactly the receiving end expects the data to come in here.

Comment: The XML is missing the namespace definitions. It is invalid.